# Multiple issues with VGA

Tags: bios, lenovo-laptop, vga, intel-graphics, windows-10-pro

Good day!
I'm facing some issues with Intel HD 4600 VGA, I will mention some:

I'm setting my resolution to 1920x1080 as follows:

[My resolution in settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2r0XY.png)

BUT in advanced display settings, this is what I'm having:

[My advanced display settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxSNM.png)

I tried everything, uninstalling drivers, updating and everything possible.

refresh rate is locked at 48 hz, can't change it & no other options at all (due to many reasons, driver is customized by Lenovo, some BIOS settings is locking it up) I successfully un-hide advanced settings in BIOS, but can't find where exactly can change refreshrate.

My screen is supporting 60 hz refresh rate...

Comment: Try updating the driver with the Intel latest release.

Comment: To see if it's hardware vs. OS, try running from a flash drive with an alternative, such as Ubuntu. I was quite surprised, on connecting a VGA monitor to a laptop running at 720p, that Ubuntu identified the monitor and switched to 1080p without intervention!

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia: Already did that with no luck as Lenovo I guess is locking vga settings through BIOS, also Lenovo is customizing Intel & GeForce drivers...

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippik: I tried many different operating systems like Windows 7,8 and Ubuntu...same issues! As per screen manufacturer, refresh rate is up to 60 hz, as per many users, Lenovo locked it at 48 hz, a previous BIOS update changed refresh rate lock from 30 to 48, so I guess its something with BIOS, already unlocked advanced settings menu but can't find where to change values...

Comment: @d3ibis I said the latest version released by **Intel**, not the manufacturer. It's an old graphics in an old laptop, supposedly. Like most manufacturers Lenovo stopped supporting it a long time ago. The driver version they offer may not be fully compatible with the Windows build you're running now but Intel should (hopefully) provide newer,  compatible, versions.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I tried that, setup version is giving error that I must using only manufacturer drivers, I downloaded ZIP version & tried to update manually and its done BUT still same issue, refresh rate is locked at 48hz, Desktop & active resolution still giving wrong values and not 1080...my only solution is to find the correct option in BIOS to change values (previously Lenovo released a bios update & refresh rate changed from locked 30hz to locked 48hz)